# Bash. Generate random mac address (unicast)

Tags: bash, random, generator, mac-address

I need to generate in bash random mac addresses without using macchanger or similar.

I have this:

```
random_mac=$(hexdump -n6 -e '/1 ":%02X"' /dev/random | sed s/^://g)
```

But with this sometimes, if you try to put the mac into the interace it says `SIOCSIFHWADDR: Cannot assign requested address`. I investigated about this and it seems something related to unicast addresses. I have a workaround working:

```
random_mac=00:$(cat /dev/urandom | tr -dc A-Za-z0-9 | head -c 200 | md5sum | sed -r 's/^(.{10}).*$/\1/;s/([0-9a-f]{2})/\1:/g; s/:$//;')
```

But I don't like too much this because is not completely random. It has always `00` at the beginning.

Any known bash random mac generator fitting the unicast rule?

I read other methods using `od`. I'm trying to use as less tools as possible in order to have less requeriments to run the script. Can be done without `od`? or is `od` absolutely always included in all Linux distros? If yes, I can use it.

Comment: How many of these are you going to generate? 40 random bits is plenty random.

Comment: The first 3 octects are the [OUI](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Organizationally_unique_identifier), can't be random

Comment: If you create mac addresses yourself, make sure [setting the second-least-significant bit of the first octet of the address.](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address#Universal_vs._local)

Comment: @DiegoTorresMilano Why do you think that? It's not like your networking gear is going to check if you have purchased an OUI.

Comment: "Any known bash random mac generator fitting the unicast rule?" What is this rule?

Comment: The "rule" is the first octet must be even. Look at this: http://askubuntu.com/questions/423530/cant-change-my-mac-address-cant-assign-requested-address/423536

Answer (score 6, accepted):

According to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/MAC_address), if the LSB on the first octet is a 0, it's a unicast address. If the 2nd LSB on the first octet is a 1, it's a locally generated MAC address.

```
0x0     0000
0x1     0001
0x2     0010
0x3     0011
0x4     0100
0x5     0101
0x6     0110
0x7     0111
0x8     1000
0x9     1001
0xA     1010
0xB     1011
0xC     1100
0xD     1101
0xE     1110
0xF     1111
```

We can see that safe first octets for locally generated MAC addresses are *x*2, *x*6, *x*A, and *x*E, as they all end in 10. Using `awk`, we can put those into an array, and then replace the second byte of the output with a random selection.

This updated version will work with either Linux or OS X:

```
#!/bin/bash
hexdump -n 6 -ve '1/1 "%.2x "' /dev/random | awk -v a="2,6,a,e" -v r="$RANDOM" 'BEGIN{srand(r);}NR==1{split(a,b,",");r=int(rand()*4+1);printf "%s%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s\n",substr($1,0,1),b[r],$2,$3,$4,$5,$6}'
```

Or, spread out a bit:

```
#!/bin/bash
hexdump -n 6 -ve '1/1 "%.2x "' /dev/random |\
awk -v a="2,6,a,e" -v r="$RANDOM" '
    BEGIN {
        srand(r);
    }
    NR==1 {
        split(a, b, ",");
        r=int(rand() * 4 + 1);
        printf("%s%s:%s:%s:%s:%s:%s\n", substr($1, 0, 1), b[r], $2, $3, $4, $5, $6);
    }
'
```

Comment: `hexdump -n 7 -ve '1/1 "%.2x "' /dev/random | awk` ... +1

Comment: Changing the beginning (before "| awk") by what @Samuel Kirschner suggested is fully working. Thank you.

Comment: @SamuelKirschner thanks for the tip, I was testing on OS X which has a slightly different output for `hexdump`.

Answer (score 3):

What about this one?

```
od -An -N6 -tx1 /dev/urandom | sed -e 's/^  *//' -e 's/  */:/g' -e 's/:$//' -e 's/^\(.\)[13579bdf]/\10/'
```

It generates a random (unicast) MAC address

- The last sed expression ensures the unicast/multicast bit is set to zero
- The greedy space replacements are for portability across UNIX seds

`od` is included in `coreutils` so you don't have to worry about 
more requirements

Comment: Nice, though you lose a bit of randomness always replacing with 0.